# Adding date to pdf export in Kendo UI

Tags: pdf, kendo-ui

This is my first time using this website. Today is my debut into Kendo UI. My boss has bought it, and set me on it with high hopes! I absolutely love it if I'm honest but I have got stuck on an issue, I have Googled every possible search phrase but can't seem find a resolve. So I'm going to post this request and go to bed, hoping for the best. I'd have had my first task done in a day if it wasn't for this niggle :/

I'm looking to add the date to a PDF export in Kendo UI.

Here is my code...

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    toolbar: ["excel", "pdf"],
                    excel: {
                        fileName: "FlexibleSalesReport-"+ fileNameDate + ".xlsx",
                        proxyURL: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export",
                        filterable: true
                    },
                    pdf: {
                        allPages: true,
                        avoidLinks: true,
                        paperSize: "A4",
                        margin: { top: "2cm", left: "0.5cm", right: "0.5cm", bottom: "1cm" },
                        landscape: true,
                        repeatHeaders: true,
                        template: $("#page-template").html(),
                        scale: 0.6,
                        date: new Date(),
                        title: 'My Title',
                        subject: 'My subject'

                    },
                    dataSource: {
                        //type: "odata",
                        // transport: {
                        //     read: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                        // },

                        data: products,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {

                                    Name: { type: "string" },
                                    WebName: { type: "string" },
                                    Code: { type: "string" },
                                    Icing: { type: "string" },
                                    Filling: { type: "string" },
                                    AssociatedOrderingPage: { type: "string" },
                                    Sold: { type: "number" },
                                    TotalValue: { type: "string "}


                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 10,
                        serverPaging: false,
                        serverFiltering: false,
                    },
                    height: 980,
                    filterable: {
                        mode: "row"
                    },
                    pageable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    columns: 
                    ['Data removed for brevity']
                });
```

I have added the date option, I'm not sure where to pull that option out of in the template. Below is my code for the template. Because it is in script tags, I cannot call functions or inject data into the span tags to add a date to the end of the of the pdf title.

```
<script type="x/kendo-template" id="page-template">

            <div class="page-template">
                <div class="header">
                <div style="float: right">Page #: pageNum # of #: totalPages #</div>
                ########### Sales Report - <span id="thisOne"></span><!-- I'd like to inject into this span, even this comment isn't commented out in my IDE {VS Code}

                </div>
                <div class="watermark">#####</div>
                <div class="footer">
                Page #: pageNum # of #: totalPages #
                </div>
            </div>
            </script>
```

[The intended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZzTU.jpg)

Thanks in advance and though I've read through the do's and don'ts. I'm open to constructive criticism on my addition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. So after more research. I found the solution which I'll share with you guys.

To define any custom Javascript in the template, you must add it between hash tags (pound signs to some people). 
For example:

```
# var foo = "bar"; #
```

Then to print the variable to the report, you use the following syntax:

```
#= foo #
```

The solution to my problem was replacing the template section with

```
<script type="x/kendo-template" id="page-template">
            #
                var theDate = new Date();

            #
            <div class="page-template">
                <div class="header">
                <div style="float: right">Page #: pageNum # of #: totalPages #</div>
                [Obfuscated for client privacy] Flexible Sales Report - <span>#=theDate#</span> 

                </div>
                <div class="watermark">[Obfuscated for client privacy]</div>
                <div class="footer">
                Page #: pageNum # of #: totalPages #: 


                </div>
            </div>
            </script>
```

I sincerely hope this helps someone.